# Defining template variables in django-registration

Tags: django, django-templates, django-registration

I am trying pass a new variable into a template within django-registration. Here is the code I have --

```
# in the template:

<table>
{% for user in user_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>

</tr>
{% endfor %}
<table>
```

Where would I put the following `user_list` definition?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
'user_list':User.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can append a new method to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py, e.g.

```
 #setting.py
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'other_contexts',
    'yourproject.yourcontextfile.yourcontextmethod',
      )
```

and then in your `yourcontextfile.py` write `yourcontextmethod` like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    def yourcontextmethod(request):
        return {'user_list':User.objects.all()}
```

Comment: excellent, this works. Thank you. Will this mean that 'user_list' is a global variable that can be used in ANY template? What happens if I define a user_list variable in a views function, will this override it?

Comment: yes, this is a global veriable. but i didn't know about overriding by a view, please try it and drop a comment

Comment: Yes, I tried it out and defining a local variable of the same name in `views.py` overrides the variable defined in the context method.